# C++ ide to run on an embedded linux device

Tags: ide, embedded-linux

I am putting together a very simple device for developing C++ applications on the go. Something like a a psp, size wise, with a small keyboard to write code and LCD screen for the output. This device has also a DVI out, so I can output to screen too.

Now, I am looking for a very lightweight C++ IDE for X11 (the device runs on a Linux variant of OpenEmbedded); something that is able to work decently on both the DVI monitor but mainly on the small lcd screen (it is a 4.3 inch screen with a 480x272 resolution).

I am aware that anything under 1024x768 is just pure joy for pain lovers, but the device will be used only in particular situations; when a laptop/netbook is not feasible.

While using the DVI out, I have no problems running Gnome, the screen is big enough to allow me to work comfortably. the problem is that it won't scale very well on the 480x272 screen.

The first idea was to use nano and g++, without even loading X11, but I need to have something with code completion and a minimal UI to do the standard operations (build, run, debugging step by step, breakpoints), if possible. The memory is not that big (256 Mb), so the smaller the IDE, the better it is.

What would you suggest, other than the approach via text editor and g++ ? I am new to the embedded linux world, I use Eclipse on Ubuntu, but that one is incredibly huge and on such small device would just kill it. On Windows I would use Dev-C++, while on Mac I use either code:blocks or Xcode, but I don't really need all these features for the device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Self-hosting dev tools on small embedded systems is not a terribly good idea.  You'd be much better off cross-compiling on a development host, and using remote debugging.

Comment: Agree, but in some cases I need a fully self functional unit to code; and I can't have even a small laptop, so the cross compiling is not possible. I can do it with vi/nano and compile with g++, but it is quite hard when you have a small keyboard and a lot of code to write

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, developing on an ODroid (http://hardkernel.com) running Linux on an ARM processor.  For a while I used Netbeans, but it was too heavy, so I finally gave up and wrote my own open source IDE for the purpose.

https://github.com/amirgeva/coide